# Kubuntu 21.10 freezes after 3-4 hours and can't reboot succesfully

Tags: kubuntu, freeze

I just installed my Kubuntu recently it and it freezes after about 3-4 hour of usage. Keyboard event still works but I can't click anything. The only way I could do is pressing power button to shutdown and power it again, but it is still freeze after rebooting. The only way I could do to make it work again is opening Live CD, run `sudo fsck -f` my linux root partition, which is /dev/sda3 in this case, reboot and my Kubuntu will successfully work again. But then the problem will happen again if I use it for several hours.
Any help is appreciated or please tell me what command to show you the log you need to help diagnostic

My laptop's spec:

- AMD Ryzen 5 4600H
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 4GB
- 256GB nvme SSD and a 500GB SATA SSD that replaced my laptop's DVD drive, which I installed my Kubuntu on /dev/sda3 (root) and /dev/sda4 (/home)

[image: Output of neofetch]

The `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3` log that last freeze I run
https://pastebin.com/MyjNxQyc

My disk layout, Kubuntu system is in /dev/sda3 and its data is in /dev/sda4

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.03 GiB, 2181812224 bytes, 4261352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZALQ256HAJD-000L2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 041498D5-49B7-44D8-98CA-239A54676E5E

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2     34816 288102399 288067584 137.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 497819648 498024447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498024448 499066879   1042432   509M Windows recovery environ
/dev/nvme0n1p5 499066880 500118158   1051279 513.3M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p6 288102400 392959999 104857600    50G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 392960000 497819647 104859648    50G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.


Disk /dev/sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: KIOXIA-EXCERIA S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 93E9C9D7-F2AA-4C42-ACF1-E19830C5F4D0

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         34   1050623   1050590   513M EFI System
/dev/sda2  223315968 537888767 314572800   150G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  537888768 689549311 151660544  72.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  689549312 929955839 240406528 114.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  929955840 937703054   7747215   3.7G Linux swap
/dev/sda6    1050624 223315967 222265344   106G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

`free -h`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,2Gi       3,2Gi       2,0Gi       206Mi       2,1Gi       3,6Gi
Swap:          3,7Gi          0B       3,7Gi
```

`grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`
Nothing showed

`grep -i sda3 /var/log/syslog*`

```
/var/log/syslog:Dec  5 10:17:28 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    1.927000]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6
/var/log/syslog:Dec  5 10:17:28 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.922339] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog:Dec  5 10:17:28 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    3.251036] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
grep: /var/log/syslog: binary file matches
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 16:19:55 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    1.809473]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 16:19:55 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.531847] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 16:19:55 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.839589] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 17:07:09 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.000007]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 17:07:09 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.766813] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  1 17:07:09 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    3.079555] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  2 07:25:29 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    1.976872]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  2 07:25:29 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    2.657364] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec  2 07:25:29 le-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05 kernel: [    3.016611] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
```

[image: SMART status of /dev/sda]

Comment: Hey, Can you tell me what apps were you using when it freezes, also as you said the keyboard works but the mouse doesn't work, I believe you are on a laptop with a touchpad, as this is a common problem, also can you post the output of `free -h` command

Comment: @someone I mainly use Vivaldi browser and Visual Code on my Kubuntu, so I think those are apps when it freezes. I added the log at the end of my thread.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Ok yeah, it is not a memory issue but can you also post the output of `neofetch` generally, it lets people know about your system specs and other things, which is useful

Comment: Thank you. I just added neofetch's screenshot after the spec section. Hope someone could help
In the meanwhile, I tried to install another Kubuntu in the other drives and wait to see if the issue still happends on this drives

Comment: Accept my edit...

Comment: Have you done a custom kernel upgrade ?

Comment: Yes. Initially, the kernel is 5.13.0-22 and the issue already happened at that time. I updated my kernel to 5.15.6 using https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Normally you should not do that ! That could cause more errors

Comment: At that time, some search results I found said kernel 5.13 doesn't have good supports with Ryzen CPU and newer versions will fix some bugs so I updated it in hope that it could fix my issue

Comment: That is true, that kernel 5.13 doesn't have support for Ryzen a lot, I also use Ryzen 9 and have the same issue but upgrading to the newest kernel version whithout testing it isn't good

Comment: I would rather wait for ubuntu 22.04 to get that kernel

Comment: Probably try booting to the old kernel

Comment: You're getting I/O errors on /dev/sda3 which **might** suggest a bad SSD. What is "Candy Bay"? Is /dev/sda3 an external USB drive? Is it a USB3 or USB2 drive... plugged into a USB3 or USB2 port? Do you dual-boot with Windows? Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i sda3 /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema /dev/sda is a SSD drive that replace my laptop's DVD drive. I added the result of your suggested commands at the end of my thread

Comment: So the SSD is a SATA drive? You dual-boot with Windows. Have you installed a Windows driver that purports to allow read/writes to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Use the `Disks` app and show me the SMART Data for the drive in question.

Comment: @heynnema is KDE partition mangager ok too? I added a screenshot of the drive's SMART log at the end of my thread

Comment: Hum, the SMART data didn't reveal anything. Let's try a mod of a previous command... do `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`. Also, you didn't answer my question about the Windows driver. Is there any chance that the drive isn't seated properly into the DVD SATA connector?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I'm very sorry for very late response. Thanks for your presistence I tried to use it a free days to see if the issue stills happen. 
Unfornately, it still happends 
1/ I updated KIOXIA's new firmware
2/ I couldn't find Samsung Magic for my SSD. Look like they don't support for this PM991 SSD
3/ the swap is rarely used. the `used` number is often stay at 0

Comment: 4/ The "The backup GPT table is corrupt," error hasn't appeared again so far. I also can't find how to rebuild GPT table without wiping data 

5/ Yes I dual-boot but I don't install any Windows driver to read Linux partitions.

6/ I recently install Kubuntu and its /home partition on my Samsung SSD and haven't seen the crash so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Freezing**

Use the `free -h` command to monitor swap `used`. If it approaches 3G, you'll need to add a /swapfile, or increase the /dev/sda5 swap partition.

**KIOXIA EXCERIA 480**

Update the firmware to the March 15, 2021 version. Also get the `SSD Utility Management Software`. Get them [here](https://personal.kioxia.com/en-emea/support/download/ssd/exceria-sata.html).

**SAMSUNG MZALQ256HAJD-000L2**

**Error**: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.

Rebuild the GPT table. `KDE Partition Manager` may be able to do it. Check the firmware. Get the `Samsung Magician` software [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/).